# 'Fictus Mundi' Latin To English Translation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

What does ''Fictus Mundi'' mean translated to English, and is it a correct Latin construct?
I have been conducting research on some early hermeticism and esoteric works, so that is where I came across this expression.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you come across this? Context can matter a lot for translation. You can edit your question to add details.

Comment: Hello, thanks!
I have been conducting research on some early hermeticism and esoteric works, so that is where I came across this expression.

Comment: Thanks! I edited that into your question. Feel free to make any further edits if you feel like it. // You have now earned enough reputation to vote up all questions and answers on you like. [Our introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) has some details. I hope to see more questions from you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in isolation, it means "the invented [male] one of the world".

Comment: Thank for the clear explanation.